# EF6 Table Splitting with foreign keys (Database first)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm currently investigating the possibility to use table splitting with EF to stop pulling too many columns for nothing. As for now, I'm able to create a new entity, cut/paste the fields into the sub-entity and map it without much problems.

However, if one of those fields is a FK in the master table, it gives me the following error
"**Running transformation: There is no property with name 'IdDocumentImportSource' defined in type referred by Role 'DocumentImports'.**"

I do understand that the both tables have a NavigationProperties that cannot be resolved anymore by the association FK because the field has been moved to the child table.

Here's my question; Is there a way to automaticaly move the association FK to the child table? I could only make it work by manually deleting the association, both navigation properties, creation the association FK of the child. It involves quite a lot of work on my part if I have to do all this manually for every association FK I got...!

DocumentImports is the ParentTable that I splitted into a new child table DocumentImports_StatusDetail and DocumentImportSources is the table being referenced by the FK.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Then navigation property `DocumentImports` should point to `DocumentImports_Statusdetail`, which, in turn, should have a navigation property `DocumentImportSources`.

Comment: I agree with you, however the navigation properties are read-only. You can't change it's destination from the designer. I also tried to change directly the association, but then again, with no results. The association is not read-only but I didn't find any way to change the destination entity.

Comment: You can do this by deleting the association and add add a new one.

Comment: Indeed I can, but as I were saying in the post, I'm looking for an automated way to do this. I have more than 50+ association FK that will be in problem if I switch to table split.

Comment: Since the FK exists in the database, I would have hoped that EF would be able to enforce it even if I'm using a split table since the mapping is 1:1